# Can you use "starts_with" as shorthand within a simple "as.numeric" function to query multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of a numeric type, where I want to query if a range of values exist in any of them, and bring back a true/false binary flag with as.numeric.

So I can do this the long way with:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(flag = as.numeric(days_dry %in% c(1:28) |
                           days_frozen %in% c(1:28) |
                           days_fresh %in% c(1:28))
```

But I have a bunch of columns I want to query. Why can't I bring back the same result with this?:

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(flag = as.numeric(vars(starts_with("days_")) %in% c(1:28))
```

I get no error, but it doesn't bring back any cases which match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but ...

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(flag = rowSums(sapply(cbind(select(., starts_with("c"))), `%in%`, 4:6)) > 0) %>%
  head()
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  flag
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  TRUE
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  TRUE
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  TRUE
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  TRUE
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 FALSE
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  TRUE
```

The premise is using `cbind(select(., <>)))` to form a mid-pipe inner frame. From there, we `sapply` over its columns, converting them to columns of logicals. The last step is using `rowSums(.) > 0` to determine if a row has at least one `TRUE`; an alternative to `rowSums` can use ```` Reduce(``` ```` | ```` ```, ...) ````, but while that is elegant in a list-processing kind of way, it is also slower (especially with multiple matching columns).